# Howto get started with C# 4.0 and .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I don't want to download Visual Studio 2010.

1. How can I start studying (not
   developing real applications) C# 4.0
   and .NET 4.0 with just a text
   editor?
2. Can I just download C# 4.0 compiler
   and .NET 4.0 framework and get
   started? How?

*I have got Visual Studio 2008 but I learn from SO questions that it can't do the job.*

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to download VS2010?  It's awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the download links:

- [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Beta 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ded875c8-fe5e-4cc9-b973-2171b61fe982&displaylang=en)
- [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Beta 2 Web Bootstrapper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9f5e8774-c8dc-4ff6-8285-03a4c387c0db&displaylang=en)

Comment: @Luke what is Web Bootstrapper? Is it necessary to download it?

Comment: @david: No, it's not necessary to download it. Choose *either* one of the standard installers from the first link *or* the web bootstrapper. From the web bootstrapper download page: *"This download consists of a new Web-based installer that simplifies the installation process."*

Answer (score 4):

The C# compiler is part of the .NET Framework.

You can find it under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\your_version_number\csc.exe

So, just open a text editor, write your source code, and compile it with the command line compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [command line compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd%28VS.100%29.aspx). Most text editors let you hook into this easily.

Answer (score 1):

You need .NET framework 4.0 (if it exists already). Compiler is part of .NET package.

Edit: Just checked and .NET framework is in beta 2 stage. Wouldn't go there just yet.

Comment: Can you please post the download links? I got lost on the MicroSoft's website.

Comment: What's wrong with studying with the beta? As david said, he won't be writing real apps.

Comment: As long as the code is for testing purposes, there is nothing wrong with beta. However, too many times I have seen "testing" code transferred to real life production environment.
Also in betas, usually, not all features work as described (if you are lucky) or even not at all.

Answer (score 1):

First go and download the [beta 2 of the .NET framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ded875c8-fe5e-4cc9-b973-2171b61fe982&displaylang=en) (current at the time of this writing).

Now, make sure `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.21006\` is in your PATH environment variable.

Here's the MSDN page for the [command-line compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd(VS.100).aspx) so you can see the options. For simple things it usually boils down to this:

```
// compile an executable
$ csc /out:App.exe *.cs
// compile a library
$ csc /target:library /out:Lib.dll *.cs
// compile with a reference to System.Core.dll
$ csc /out:App.exe /r:System.Core.dll *.cs
// compile with a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll (you might need this to use dynamic)
$ csc /out:App.exe /r:Microsoft.CSharp.dll *.cs
```

Of course try to use an editor with syntax highlighting. I believe C# 4 only introduces three new keywords, so you should be fine even with highlighting for version 3 (`in` and `out` already existed, but they are now valid in a new context and `dynamic` is entirely new).

Comment: My fingers are wired to work in vim, but I don't like to recommend on religious matters ;) My usual advice is to pick a decent one (i.e. no Notepad) and learn out to use it to the best.